# Убрать пробелы вначале в инпуте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть функция `onChange`, где в стейт записываю то, что ввели в инпут

```
onChange = id => currentValue => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: {
           ...prevState.data,
         [id]: currentValue
        }
    }));
};
```

но есть ситуация, когда сначала в инпут ввели пробел или несколько пробелов. мне нужно игнорировать пробелы вначале и убирать их. При этом чтобы в инпуте на `onChange` данное поведение отображалось.
То есть сделали фокус на инпуте, ввели несколько пробелов, начали писать, например email и курсор в этот момент ушел вначало,словно пробелов не было

Comment: ну так не обновляйте состояние input если, value - не валидно...

Comment: такой вариант не пойдет. тогда не будет возможности писать невалидные данные. а я хочу иметь возможность писать невалидные данные в инпуте. но если вдруг пробелы вначале, то курсор перемещается вначало
вот тут похожее поведение на форме в поле емейла https://www.tinkoff.ru/cards/credit-cards/s7-airlines/?internal_source=mainbanner#start

Comment: ну тогда вам нужно проверять перед обновлением состояния есть ли вначале строки "не пробельные символы", если их нету - то рендер как есть (будут только пробелы), как только появятся видимые символы, тут же вырезаете все пробелы сначала строки и выводите строку

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim). Этот метод позволяет удалять пробелы, табы в начале и в конце строки. `str.trim()`